# Generalized Sard's lemma

Tags: singularity-theory, morse-theory, critical-point-theory

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{1,1}$ (that is $C^1$ with Lipschitz differential) function on a manifold $X$. Suppose that $f$ is smooth at all points of a subset $C \subset \text{Crit}f$ of critical points.

Does Sard's lemma hold in this case, that is, does the set $f(C)$ is of zero measure ? If it does, could someone give me a hint why ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sard's lemma applies to $f$ restricted to any nbd $N$ of the critical set, so it is sufficient $f_{|N}\in C^k(N)$ $k\ge \dim(X)$

Comment: What do you mean by smooth on $C$? If you only know that $f\in C^{1,1}$, then Sard's theorem hold if $\dim X\leq 2$ otherwise there are counterexamples. If you clarify your question I can provide an answer.